# Typescript error for Icon from react-native-elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-elements

I am getting a typescript error when I try to use icons from react-native-elements.

This is the error.

> Property 'tvParallaxProperties' is missing in type '{ type: string; name: string; color: string; size: number; }' but required in type 'Pick<IconButtonProps & { type?: string | undefined; Component?: typeof Component | undefined; reverse?: boolean | undefined; raised?: boolean | undefined; containerStyle?: StyleProp<...>; ... 5 more ...; brand?: boolean | undefined; } & Partial<...>, "backgroundColor" | ... 68 more ... | "brand">'.

Versions:

"react-native": "^0.64.1",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",

How can I fix this error?